# Is it possible to watch for new posts with Instagram Webhooks?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Currently in the developing stages of a web app that will allow users to connect their Instagram & Facebook via OAuth then enable an automation that will send new IG posts to their Facebook.

Is there an IG Graph Webhook available for this? Or will I need to set up an API call from my app to watch for the new posts.

I also have an app created & verified with Meta already as a business app. I'm wondering if this was the right decision to create it as a business or should it be a consumer app.

When subscribing to a webhook, I was not able to locate anything to subscribe to 'new posts'.

If the next option is to set up an API call to watch for new posts for every 'x' amount of minutes is there an endpoint and headers that is provided in the docs to set this up?

Any other avenues on how to successfully get this feature up would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: New posts made by whom? Just _anyone_ on Instagram? No, there is no webhook for that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks/: _"Webhooks for Instagram allow you to receive real-time notifications whenever someone comments on the Media objects of your app users; @mentions your app users; or when Stories of your app users expire."_

Comment: New posts made by the users of my app after they have connected their Instagram & Facebook account via OAuth. 

Will I need to create an API call for this action?

Comment: Subscribing to IG webhooks works via the app dashboard, I think.